# How to get hardcoded radio values from thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

is there a way to get manually created html checkbox option values using thymeleaf? I created html checkbox like this,

```
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">Is Retail</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="2">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">Is Wholesale</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="3">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">Is Warranty</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

for example if I select

> is warranty

checkbox I need to show/ hide some input elements in my form.
can this be done using thymeleaf or do i have to use java-script for do this show/ hide thing.

Comment: Thymeleaf is just an HTML templating framework. If you want any kind of dynamic behaviour (i.e. hiding / showing elements), you will need to use JavaScript.

Comment: hi @Michael , is there a way to do something like this, get selected value from checkbox and using **expression language** and show/hide the elements in the form using thymeleaf?

Comment: Thymeleaf expressions are evaluated at the time the HTML is generated. They cannot be used for dynamic behaviour.

Comment: You will have to use javascript because of what other comments explain. You can call your function adding something like onchange="onMyCheckboxChanged()" to the input element.